# How to send parameter in modal bootsrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, bootstrap-modal

Demo and full code is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/xzxrp7nn/9/

My HTML code is like this :

```
<button type="button">Click Me</button>

<div id="tes"></div>

<!-- Modal Currency-->
<div class="modal fade" id="priceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

My Javascript code is like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                //type: 'POST',
                //url: 'script.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    var priceModal = '{"attributes":{"Code":"DBL","Total":"200000"},"DayPrice":{"Date":"2016-05-26","Rate":"200000"}}';

                    var isitable = '<button class="btn blue tes_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#priceModal" id="priceModal='+priceModal+'">Test get parameter json array</button>';
                    $("#tes").html(isitable);
                }
            });
        });

        $('#priceModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
             //console.log('yes');
            var param = e.relatedTarget.id;
            // var hotel_code = $(this).data('id');
            console.log(param);
            // console.log(hotel_code);
        })
    });
```

When click button "Click me", It will display button "Test get parameter json array".

When click button "Test get parameter json array", I want send parameter `priceModal` to modal. Parameter `priceModal` contain json array. I do console.log(param); in `$('#priceModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {`.

But the result : `priceModal={`. 
It failed to get the value of priceModal

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you

Comment: What is this `id="priceModal='+priceModal+'"`? do you mean to add your json to your element's id like that? `data-price-modal="+priceModal+'"` would be far more appropirate

Comment: Agree with @DelightedD0D. That is not a id

Comment: @mosestoh All you want to get `priceModal` value in model??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `id="priceModal='+priceModal+'"` you are incorrectly appending your json to your element's id.

A data attribute would be far more appropriate, something more like this:

```
success: function(data) {
  var priceModal = {"attributes":{"Code":"DBL","Total":"200000"},"DayPrice":{"Date":"2016-05-26","Rate":"200000"}};
  var isitable = '<button class="btn blue tes_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#priceModal" data-price-modal="">Test get parameter json array</button>';
  $("#tes").html(isitable).find('[data-price-modal]').data('price-modal',priceModal);
}


$('#priceModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var param = $('[data-price-modal]').data('price-modal');
  console.log(param);
})
```

#### [working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzxrp7nn/13/)

---

Alternatively, you could have your server return the JSON string encoded for use in the attribute. For example, if you were using `php`, this would work:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode(someArray), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: The result of  `console.log(param);` :  `{`

Comment: @mosestoh my bad, I forgot that JSON is a bit of a pain in this context. See my edit, its actually easier to add the object with jQuery and let it handle the details

Comment: it looks like I will use this way : https://jsfiddle.net/o5qn5gum/2/. But there exist error

Comment: @mosestoh that jsFiddle does not use the code from the above

Comment: Look the new fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/o5qn5gum/3/. I add `console.log(JSON.parse(json));`. There exist error : `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 96 of the JSON data`.

Comment: @mosestoh again, your jsFiddle does not use the code from my answer. My answer does not use JSON.parse. it is not needed.

Comment: Solved. Surplus double quotes in `var isitable = '<button class="btn blue tes_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#priceModal" id="priceModel" data-json='+priceModal+'">Test get parameter json array</button>';`. Thank you very much

Comment: Look here : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/o5qn5gum/5/. If there are a lot of buttons, how to get the parameters? I try `$(this).attr ("Data-json");`. But it's not working

Comment: Or look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224595/how-to-send-parameter-based-on-which-button-is-clicked-in-modal

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280802/how-to-change-amcharts-pie-themes

Answer (score 1):

Place your `JSON` in **[HTML5 data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)**

```
var priceModal = "{'attributes':{'Code':'DBL','Total':'200000'},'DayPrice':{'Date':'2016-05-26','Rate':'200000'}}";

var isitable = '<button class="btn blue tes_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#priceModal" id="priceModel" data-json='+priceModal+'">Test get parameter json array</button>';
```

Access `JSON` data upon clicking newly Created button.

```
var json = $("#priceModel").attr("data-json");
$(".modal-body").html(json); //For eg.
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jenson555/o5qn5gum/7/)**

Comment: I dont think this will quite work, see this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5qn5gum/2/), Im pretty sure you need to encode the string to be able to get anything useful back out of it later, if you set it in the html itself

Comment: @DelightedD0D Have you checked given Fiddle URL??

Comment: @DelightedD0D, It looks like I will use this way. But when I try the jsfiddle, there is exist error. The error : `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`. It looks like it failed to convert to objects

Comment: exactly, thats what Im saying, youd have to encode the string on the server if you want to do it this way

Comment: @Jenson M John, when convert to object, it's not working

Comment: Solved. Surplus double quotes in `var isitable = '<button class="btn blue tes_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#priceModal" id="priceModel" data-json='+priceModal+'">Test get parameter json array</button>';`. Thank you very much