# How to send parameter based on which button is clicked in modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, bootstrap-modal

Demo and full code is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/o5qn5gum/5/

My HTML code is like this :

```
<button type="button">Click Me</button>

<div id="tes">

</div>


<!-- Modal Currency-->
<div class="modal fade" id="priceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">


            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

My Javascript code is like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                //type: 'POST',
                //url: 'script.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    // alert(data);
                    // $("p").text(data);
                    var priceModal1 = '[{"@attributes":{"Code":"SGL","Total":"200000"},"DayPrice":{"Date":"2016-05-26","Rate":"200000"}},{"@attributes":{"Code":"DBL","Total":"200000"},"DayPrice":{"Date":"2016-05-26","Rate":"200000"}}]';
                    var priceModal2 = '[{"@attributes":{"Code":"SGL","Total":"225000"},"DayPrice":{"Date":"2016-05-26","Rate":"225000"}},{"@attributes":{"Code":"DBL","Total":"225000"},"DayPrice":{"Date":"2016-05-26","Rate":"225000"}}]';
                    var priceModal3 = '[{"@attributes":{"Code":"SGL","Total":"410000"},"DayPrice":{"Date":"2016-05-26","Rate":"410000"}},{"@attributes":{"Code":"DBL","Total":"410000"},"DayPrice":{"Date":"2016-05-26","Rate":"410000"}}]';

                    var isitable = '';
                    isitable += '<br><button class="btn blue tes_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#priceModal" id="priceModel1" data-json='+priceModal1+'>Test get parameter json array 1</button><br><br>';
                    isitable += '<button class="btn blue tes_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#priceModal" id="priceModel2" data-json='+priceModal2+'>Test get parameter json array 2</button><br><br>';
                    isitable += '<button class="btn blue tes_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#priceModal" id="priceModel3" data-json='+priceModal3+'>Test get parameter json array 3</button><br>';

                    console.log(isitable);
                    $("#tes").html(isitable);

                }
            });
        });

        $('#priceModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
             //console.log('yes');

            var json = $(this).attr("data-json");
            $(".modal-body").html(json);
            console.log("JSON »» From priceModel Element "+json);
            console.log(JSON.parse(json));

        })
    });
```

When click button "Click me", It will display three button. Look jsfidde.

When click button "Test get parameter json array 1", I want send parameter priceModal1 to modal. 
When click button "Test get parameter json array 2", I want send parameter priceModal2 to modal
When click button "Test get parameter json array 3", I want send parameter priceModal3 to modal
Parameter priceModal1, priceModal2 and priceModal3  contain json array. I do

```
console.log("JSON »» From priceModel Element "+json);
            console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

in `$('#priceModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {.`

But it's not working.

Although I using : `$(this).attr("data-json");`

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you

Comment: It should be: `data-json="'+priceModal1+'">`. notice the double quotes around value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside the `show.bs.modal` event, refers to the modal itself, while the `json` data attribute is set at the button. You can access the button that triggered the event at `e.relatedTarget`.

```
var json = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-json');
```

Furthermore, accessing a `data-` attribute with `$.data` will automatically parse JSON. So you could instead write:

```
var json = $(e.relatedTarget).data('json');
```

... and skip `JSON.parse`, as `json` is now an object and not a string.

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280802/how-to-change-amcharts-pie-themes